# How to find out if an element is passed while scrolling?

Tags: javascript, scroll

I am trying to find out when I have passed certain element while scrolling.

```
  const elementTarget = document.getElementById('sidebar');

  window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    if (window.scrollY > elementTarget.offscrollTop) {
      console.log('passed an element');
    }
  })
```

sample code: https://codepen.io/RomanKomprs/pen/LMrPNJ

**EDITED:**
The code above doesn't work. When I scroll down and the scrollY is bigger than the offset of my sidebar element the condition doesn't trigger. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: take a look to IntersectionObserver

Comment: You should get familiar with logging expected results in your function and checking what they are in a console. `console.log(elementTarget.offscrollTop)` is `undefined`, because that isn't a valid property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `offscrollTop` with `getBoundingClientRect().top`

```
const elementTarget = document.getElementById("sidebar");

window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
  if (window.scrollY > elementTarget.getBoundingClientRect().top) {
    console.log("passed an element");
  }
});
```

[Try it](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZVREjZ?editors=1111)

Comment: The event triggers too early. It hasn't reach the element yet when it console log the passed ...

Comment: When you say an element is _passed_, you mean it started overflowing from the top of the screen?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: Try replacing `if (window.scrollY > elementTarget.getBoundingClientRect().top)` with `if (elementTarget.getBoundingClientRect().top < 0)`

Comment: With the previous code if (window.scrollY > elementTarget.getBoundingClientRect().top) the element is passed is displayed too early before it is scrolled to the element. Do you know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to elements with equal id;
Second you need to use .offsetTop for get value of offset;

```
if (window.scrollY > elementTarget1.offsetTop) {
  console.log('passed an element');
}
```

[codepen.io/anon/pen/LMrYMZ](http://%20codepen.io/anon/pen/LMrYMZ)